# MongoDB C# - Exchanging elements between documents

Tags: mongodb

Let's take an object:

```
class A
{
    int Value;
}
```

and I want to do this (pseudo code):

```
Document1.Value -= X;
Document2.Value += X;
```

Since I can't select two documents at once, I have to make it two transactions (Take X from Document1 and put X to Document2).

What is the best strategy to minimize risks (crash, power-off, errors, etc) while doing the transfer.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally depending on the use-case but it's common to use two phase commits, It can be read about in the mongodb documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/

However two-phase commit is not limited to mongodb and is use elses in applications.

Comment: I have a 'hold' system in place which is similar to this article: I hold a specific amount from Document1 into a field in Document1, then update Document2 and, release or confirm the hold in Document1 depending on how it went; But it's not really ideal

Comment: No matter what solution you go for, you're trying to achieve a recoverable state within the system. I've used queues for this before with slip routing or sagas. Why is your solution not ideal?

Comment: That means I have to do a tool that can scan and find transactions that have been hanging out there unfinished, just in case we have a reboot, etc. But yes, there is no perfect solution for this

Comment: You have the same issues with queues, with any system a decent amount of monitoring with these things helps a lot! You could also write something that checks invalid states so it could self-heal.